# switch from one navigation Controller to another navigation View Controller

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am developing an application in which  I am using two navigation Controllers , and uilocalNotification

first NavigationViewController N1 has two ViewControllers v1 and v2 
second NavigationViewController N2 has two ViewControllers v3 and v4

Also , when application is in background , and if UILocalNotification appears and if I click on it , the application should detect which navigation Controller and which viewController is displayed and then switch to another navigationController's viewcontroller .

Ex:- 
If v2  in N1 is displayed , then 
after notification is clicked , 
then switched to v3 in N2 is displayed

How to do this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just paste this bellow methods in your `AppDelegate.m` file and call particular method when you want to change `UINavigationController`...

For Example: if you are in `v2` of `N1` and notification changed then call bellow method like bellow...

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate setRootViewControllerN2];
```

use this bellow methods for switch navigation controller with animations..

**1. setRootViewControllerN1** : this is for set RootViewController with N1 navigationController.

```
-(void)setRootViewControllerN1{
    self.window.rootViewController = N1;
    
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self];   
    [animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
    [animation setDuration:0.5];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
                                  kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [[self.window layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:kAnimationKey];
}
```

**2. setRootViewControllerN2** : this is for set RootViewController with N2 navigationController.

```
-(void)setRootViewControllerN2{
    self.window.rootViewController = N2;
    
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self];   
    [animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
    [animation setDuration:0.5];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
                                  kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [[self.window layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:kAnimationKey];
}
```

Comment: No ! Actually , how would you determine which viewcontroller and which navigationController is being displayed right now when the notification is clicked ...???

Comment: Just Create one BOOL Variable in your AppDelegate or in UserDEfault save this one value and switch that from true to flase .. when notification occured at that time check that if true then just call second method and set that variable as a false  otherwise call first method and set variable as a True...

Comment: I thought of standardUserDefaults earler , but later I thought there would be some standard way for this . Anyways , thanx !!